# Cryptogram with one frequent letter and other letters random

Tags: cipher, unsolved-mysteries

I arrived at this ciphertext as a result of a particular decryption step from the famous unsolved "Kryptos 4" cipher. It has a very unusual letter distribution:

?QGIYWJUJEAOKGOTKKCGGXGMYPLTOYGFNOPIOZPOMBLOQCCWT
?DONNIOHBRXBMEFJAOXOOLXETCQEYNTZPMFUNENWXOWXFLYRZ

Out of 98 letters, it has 13 O's but no more than 6 of any other letter. The remaining letters appear to occur in a normal random distribution: 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, and two ? letters. Does anyone have an idea about what type of encryption method may have produced such an unusual letter distribution?

The two letters that do not appear in the cryptogram are S and V, so the very frequent O's and the lack of S's make me think of Morse code, but I can't find or think of any encryption method that could have simply resulted in 13 O's, no S's, and normal random distribution of all other letters. Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like a simple substitution cipher of some sort. The fact there is 13 Os is not unusual at all, 13/98 is about 13%, and the letter 'e' makes up 12.7% of english text. Try a ROT16 decode, and if not try some substitution cipher decoders online.

Comment: But if it were a simple substitution cipher, the distribution of the other letters would not be the way that they are. There would certainly be more than 6 of some other letter, and the distribution of all other letters would not be so even as it is here.

Comment: Not necessarily. 98 letters is a very small sample size for cryptanalysis, and therefore making assumptions off things such as frequency analysis aren't going to be reliable. The distribution could easily be like this. Considering 't' makes up 9%, the second highest, and 6/98 is about 6%, its not too far off to be unreasonable for just 98 letters.

Comment: I disagree, and a simple test of substitution decoders turns up nothing, but here, try it yourself: ?QGIYWJUJEAOKGOTKKCGGXGMYPLTOYGFNOPIOZPOMBLOQCCWT?DONNIOHBRXBMEFJAOXOOLXETCQEYNTZPMFUNENWXOWXFLYRZ. Even with just 100 letters, you don't find plain English text with a letter distribution of this sort. If you are familiar with the concept of the "Index of Coincidence", it is far too low to be a simple substitution of English text.

Comment: Again I'm not sure how reliable IoC is for such a small sample size. I do agree that it indicates a polyalphabetic cipher rather than mono, but it's going to be incredibly difficult to get anywhere with cryptanalysis for either, you're gonna want a much larger sample, or some prior knowledge of what might be in the text or something along those lines. I still think that this could be both mono or polyalphabetic as there is evidence for both. Also I recommend editing the cipher into the question, might help people here

Comment: Could it be a 5x5 Bifid cipher, with the ? replacing one of the missing letters?

Comment: Where is the cipher from?  Do you have any further information on it?  (Like, say, anything that might have implications for how complex it was likely to be?)

Comment: Sure. I wanted to ask the question without context first in order to get unbiased responses and ideas. The context is that I arrived at this cipher text as a result of a particular decryption step from the famous unsolved "Kryptos 4" cipher. I was simply quite surprised to get 13 O's in the text, when one would expect the letters to appear completely random. I'm looking for ideas about where to go from here, and wondered if anyone had any good ideas.

Comment: I kind of had a feeling it was Kryptos with that 98 reference.  Spent over a year on it in my spare time.  Learned a lot about cryptography and loads of other fields.